# Comparing 2 lists of String type containing dates but need to ignore the format

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have 2 lists which contains exact similar dates but the formatting is different. How can I compare those 2 lists are equal ignoring the format of the date?

Eg:

**List 1:**

```
[2016-07-22, 2016-07-20, 2016-07-18, 2016-07-18, 2016-07-18, 2016-07-20, 2016-07-18]
```

**List 2:**

```
[22.07.2016, 20.07.2016, 18.07.2016, 18.07.2016, 18.07.2016, 20.07.2016, 18.07.2016]
```

Let me know if there is anyway I can do this.

Comment: Parse the dates in both lists so that you have two lists with actual dates. Then compare those two lists.

Comment: You have `List<String>` right ?

Comment: Yes I have List<String>.

Comment: @RV_Dev check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

You can use this logic to compare two date.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sf1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat sf2= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date date1=sf1.parse("2016-07-18");
    Date date2=sf2.parse("18.07.2016");
    boolean bol=date1.compareTo(date2)==0;
    System.out.println(bol);//true if two dates are equal, false if two date are not equal
```

**Example**

```
    Date[] dl1={sf1.parse("2016-07-22"), sf1.parse("2016-07-20"), sf1.parse("2016-07-18"), sf1.parse("2016-07-18"), sf1.parse("2016-07-18"), sf1.parse("2016-07-20"), sf1.parse("2016-07-18")};
    Date[] dl2={sf2.parse("22.07.2016"), sf2.parse("20.07.2016"), sf2.parse("18.07.2016"), sf2.parse("18.07.2016"), sf2.parse("18.07.2016"), sf2.parse("20.07.2016"), sf2.parse("18.07.2016")};

    List<Date> l1= Arrays.asList(dl1);
    List<Date> l2= Arrays.asList(dl2);



    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();i++){
        if(l1.get(i).compareTo(l2.get(i))==0){
            System.out.println("Date matched");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Date did not matched");
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Date matched
Date matched
Date matched
Date matched
Date matched
Date matched
Date matched
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the dates:

```
List<String> list1 = // ...
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
List<LocalDate> dates1 = list1.stream()
                              .map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, formatter1))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());

// same with list2 and an adapted formatter
List<String> list2 = // ...
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
List<LocalDate> dates2 = list2.stream()
                              .map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, formatter2))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean equal = dates1.equals(dates2);
```

Comment: `->` what is that operator called? I didn't see that before in java.

Comment: It's  a Java8  expression. Lambda.

Comment: @Jean Logeart : java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '22.07.2016' could not be parsed at index 0.

Comment: I did the same thing still getting same error. 
Shouldn't this be as .collect(Collector.toList());